# Can't connect to MySQL using command line but can using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am successfully using MySQLWorkbench to access and manage a database at 127.0.0.1:3307.

However if I try to access it using the command line:

```
mysql -u admin -h 127.0.0.1:3307 -p
```

I get the error message:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3307' (0)
```

Why does it work with MySQLWorkbench and not with the command line?

I am running on OSX

Comment: just remove the port from the host definition. If this doesn't work use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Do you run the command line on the same computer as the workbench? Do you have personal firewall installed and configured?

Comment: Yes it is on same computer and no firewall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because MySQLWorkbench parses out the port number, and the CLI tool doesn't. There is a separate option `--port` for providing it. Try

```
mysql --user admin --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3307 --password
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the access problem. It now won't accept the password but that is a different issue :)

Answer (score 5):

Try to specify connection protocol

```
mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -p --port=3307 --protocol=tcp

mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -p --port=3307 --protocol=socket
```